# SQL retrieving columns which aren't in a Aggregate or Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Ok I am representing a matrix with three columns in a table. For simplicity sake: Columns A,B and Value. A and B represent the X and Y "coordinates" of the matrix.

Could someone please help me work out the following:

For each column in the matrix (X), I wish to retrieve the smallest Value AND the Y coordinate field, which represented this smallest Value in column X.

This is for each column/X in the matrix.

I have been struggling because I couldnt include Y in a group by or aggregate function, so it wouldnt let me return it in the same query as calculating the minimum value (X was GROUP BY'd).

EDIT If there are two or more rows, the minimum Y value should be returned.

Just to be clear, my table is therefore:

Y | X | Value

0 | 0 | 0.38

1 | 0 | 0.72

2 | 0 | 0.13

3 | 0 | 0.45

0 | 1 | 0.52

1 | 1 | 0.23

2 | 1 | 0.84

3 | 1 | 0.15

0 | 2 | 0.52

1 | 2 | 0.04

2 | 2 | 0.04

3 | 2 | 0.15

With the above test data, it should return:

X | Y | Value

0 | 2 | 0.13

1 | 3 | 0.15

2 | 1 | 0.04

Please note on the Y=2, row 1 was the smallest Y, even though row 2 also had the minimum value.

Comment: And what if there are 2 or more rows with same minimum value for a column?

Comment: @ypercube Thanks, I forgot to include that part!

Comment: It seems the result you show is for `GROUP BY y` and then get the lowest `Value` (and smallest `x` in case of ties). Your desription is the otehr way around.

Comment: @ypercube, no i just showed the Y column first in the results :)

Comment: Where is the result for column with `X=0` ?

Comment: @Fixed. Beg your pardon. Is your answer still valid?

Comment: Yes, try it as it is, or change it into `(PARTITION BY y ORDER BY Value, x)` for the reverse grouping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT x
     , y
     , value
FROM
  ( SELECT x
         , y
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY Value, y) AS rn 
         , Value
    FROM tableX
  ) AS tmp
WHERE rn = 1 ;
```

You can test it at: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7cd02/1)
(corrected to reflect the changed data in the question: [test-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65bbe/2))

An index on `(x, value, y)` will be useful for performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  y ,
        ( SELECT    MIN(x)
          FROM      user997112 i
          WHERE     i.Y = o.y
                    AND i.VALUE = o.VALUE
        ) AS x ,
        value
FROM    ( SELECT    y ,
                    MIN(VALUE) AS value
          FROM      dbo.user997112
          GROUP BY  y
        ) AS o
```

Here is the schema I used

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user997112](
    [x] [int] NULL,
    [y] [int] NULL,
    [VALUE] [decimal](5, 2) NULL
) 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[user997112] ([x], [y], [VALUE]) VALUES (0, 0, CAST(0.38 AS Decimal(5, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[user997112] ([x], [y], [VALUE]) VALUES (1, 0, CAST(0.72 AS Decimal(5, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[user997112] ([x], [y], [VALUE]) VALUES (2, 0, CAST(0.13 AS Decimal(5, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[user997112] ([x], [y], [VALUE]) VALUES (3, 0, CAST(0.45 AS Decimal(5, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[user997112] ([x], [y], [VALUE]) VALUES (0, 1, CAST(0.52 AS Decimal(5, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[user997112] ([x], [y], [VALUE]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(0.23 AS Decimal(5, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[user997112] ([x], [y], [VALUE]) VALUES (2, 1, CAST(0.84 AS Decimal(5, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[user997112] ([x], [y], [VALUE]) VALUES (3, 1, CAST(0.15 AS Decimal(5, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[user997112] ([x], [y], [VALUE]) VALUES (0, 2, CAST(0.52 AS Decimal(5, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[user997112] ([x], [y], [VALUE]) VALUES (1, 2, CAST(0.04 AS Decimal(5, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[user997112] ([x], [y], [VALUE]) VALUES (2, 2, CAST(0.04 AS Decimal(5, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[user997112] ([x], [y], [VALUE]) VALUES (3, 2, CAST(0.15 AS Decimal(5, 2)))
```

Comment: He wants it for EACH x value in the table

Comment: @user997112 Ok, that makes sense now. The answer is update and should give you what you need. Let me know how it goes

Comment: @buckley- will do tomorrow as havent got the system at the mo.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, but it's ungainly:

```
SELECT X, MIN(Y), Value 
FROM your_table fullTable   
WHERE Value <= ALL (SELECT Value FROM your_table WHERE X = fullTable.X)  
GROUP BY X, Value
```

This will probably be more performant if you have no index on Value.  Otherwise you will probably get better performance from

```
SELECT X, MIN(Y), Value   
FROM your_table fullTable   
WHERE Value = (SELECT MIN(Value) FROM your_table WHERE X = fullTable.X)  
GROUP BY X, Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT Test.X, Test.Y, MAX(Test.Value) AS Value FROM Test 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT X, MIN(Y) AS Y FROM Test
GROUP BY X) t 
ON Test.X = t.X AND Test.Y = t.Y 
GROUP BY Test.X, Test.Y
```

Basicly: first do a subquery to get the combinations of X with  minimum Y, then join that to the original table, to get the corresponding value

Comment: I don't think this will work unless the minimum value occurs in the tuple with the minimum Y value as well

For example: X/Y/Value = {0, 0, 5}, {0, 2, 2}

Comment: @Mark, I made a little mistake in my question. Please see the swapped X and Y columns.

Answer (score 0):

I hope im right on time!

```
Select t1.A,
    min(t1.B),
    t1.value 
from `table` t1, 
 (SELECT MIN( value ) AS value, a
  FROM  `table` 
  GROUP BY (A)) `t2`
where t1.A = t2.A
group by (t1.a)
```

Giving you  first the smallest value for A and then, grouping by B

Comment: Needs several corrections. Hint: you are not using `t2.value` anywhere.

Comment: sorry, forgot about the value